# Getting following exception org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException

Tags: java

I am getting following error while executing my java code. What is this error and how it can be removed? I googled and mostly people have talked bugs related to bcel.
Can anyone direct me to the relevant website with details. Thanks for your time.

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException: 
  FOUND:
  INTERNAL ERROR: Oops!
  Exiting!!

  at org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException.main(AssertionViolatedException.java:102)
```

Comment: What's your project? Any sample code? Something that gives us some idea of what you're doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is thrown when BCEl tries to verify bytecode modifications and fails.
You are clearly doing something (either yourself or through some tool) that uses BCEL to modify the bytecode your Java compiler produces. 
If you are working with BCEL yourself, you should be able to figure out what you are doing and why this breaks.
If it's a tool, figure out which one and report a bug. Typical candidates are things like code coverage tools, badly coded AOP stuff or some crazy research tool.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix it. Actually its weird but if I don't run the code **rather** execute its with the option of debug as java application then this exception is no longer there.

Comment: This is odd. If you are willing to share your code, I'd love to take a look at that (not so much to fix your problem, but to understand why running it as "debug" makes the exception go away).

Comment: @ Jochen, I just copied the file contents in a new project(manually copy pasting the contents of old file to a new file) latter I did include all the user libraries for building but when I tried to run the code it gave me this error. This happened with me couple of times(while using this manual process). As I started debugging the code this error went away.

Comment: Again, this is odd. Without seeing the code I can only guess. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on java program, select Run As and > "Java Application".

[image]