# HTML UNIT FOUND: INTERNAL ERROR: Oops! Exiting

Tags: htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I'm new to the HTMLUNIT, When I run the below code.

```java
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

public class WeBrowser {

    public void homePage() throws Exception {

        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        // Get the first page
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");
        // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form,
        // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
        final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("myform");
        final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submitbutton");
        final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("userid");
        // Change the value of the text field
        textField.setValueAttribute("root");
        // Submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
        final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }
}
```

It shows the following Error :

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException: 

FOUND:
INTERNAL ERROR: Oops!
Exiting!!

at org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException.main(AssertionViolatedException.java:102)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I have almost same problem, Alhtough it looks odd but try by debugging rather than running, or add some delay before clicking submit button

```
    Thread.sleep(10000);
```

and also take a look at this answer [AssertionViolatedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609066/getting-following-exception-org-apache-bcel-verifier-exc-assertionviolatedexcept)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error using eclipse to run java code that had previously worked ok. After using 'project>>clean>>all projects' the problem disappeared. Don't know what triggered it but all projects in the workspace were affected.