# How to write Selenium Java Application code in IDE through main() and TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

I m facing the below issue 
  searched in Google couldn't find the clear answer how to resolve this.

Error :

```
org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException.main(AssertionViolatedException.java:102)
```

**Code**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Newtours 
{ 
     public static ChromeDriver driver; 
     public void chrome() 
    {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\imper\\Downloads\\chro‌​medriver_win32\\chro‌​medriver.exe"); // objects and variables instantiation 
         driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
         driver.get("newtours.demoaut.com/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code trials and relevant HTML please.

Comment: Not having any HTML relevant. Try to run the application in eclipse   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class Newtours {

 
   public static ChromeDriver  driver;
    
    public void chrome()  {
     System.setProperty( "webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\imper\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    // objects and variables instantiation
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
     
}} faced the mentioned issue

Comment: Edit the Question and update this code block and the error you see for proper analysis.

Comment: check out this link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609066/getting-following-exception-org-apache-bcel-verifier-exc-assertionviolatedexcept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609066/getting-following-exception-org-apache-bcel-verifier-exc-assertionviolatedexcept)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is stemming out of **`org.apache.bcel.verifier`**

You have to take care of a certain things as follows :

Instead of using the **`ChromeDriver`** implementation use the **`WebDriver`** interface.
    **`chrome`** is a reserved keyword. Use some other user defined name for the **method** e.g. `my_function() {}`
    Simply defining **public void chrome()** won't execute your `Test`. You have to convert **public void chrome()** in to either of the following :

- Convert into `main()` function as follows:

  ```
      public class Newtours  
      {
          public static void main(String[] args) 
          {
              System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
              WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();
              driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
          }
      }
  ```
- Integrate `TestNG` and add **`@Test`** annotations as follows :

  ```
      import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
      import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
      import org.testng.annotations.Test;

      public class Newtours 
      {
          @Test
          public void my_function()
          {
              System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
              WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
              driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
          }
      }
  ```

Comment: tried as said Exception in thread "main" org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException: 
FOUND:
 INTERNAL ERROR: Oops!
Exiting!!

 at org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException.main(AssertionViolatedException.java:102)   --- facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
```

Try this code it's working fine.
I checked this and it's running fine.
You need to give **http** or **https** for your url.