# Getting Null pointer exception while running the below script using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

```
public class TestBase {
    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static Properties prop = null;
    public TestBase() {
        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("C:\\seleniumFolder\\SampleMavenProject\\src\\main\\java\\com\\crm\\qa\\config\\config.properties");
            prop.load(ip);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void initialization() {
        String browsername = prop.getProperty("browser");
        if (browsername.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\seleniumFolder\\chromedriver.exe ");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line are you seeing the exception?

Comment: Your initialization method should consider the else-case. Right now it runs into a nullpointer-exception if browsername is not equal to "chrome", which is bad. Also, considering https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String): browsername can potentially be null, thus your if-check should call equals() on the literal "chrome" instead of your variable browsername.

Comment: Thank you! I have removed if check and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your `FileInputStream ip` is not getting initialized. You have to provide `(\\)` instead of `(\)` as follows :

```
FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("C:\\seleniumFolder\\SampleMavenProject\\src\\main\\java\com\\crm\\qa\\config\\config.properties");
```

---

### Update

You are seeing `java.lang.NullPointerException` because to execute a *Java Program* you have to initiate the execution through a `main()` method or `@Test` annotated method (if using TestNG).

So if you want to execute this program through `main()` method you have to put the current code of `public static void initialization()` method into `public static void main(String[] args)` method and execute the program as a *Java Program*.

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to write Selenium Java Application code in IDE through main() and TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018053/how-to-write-selenium-java-application-code-in-ide-through-main-and-testng/48018950#48018950)

Comment: That was my fault, the formatter I used to fixed the code broke that