# AssertionViolatedException still occur using eclipse

Tags: java, selenium

I tried running this code in my laptop. I followed all the instruction showed in Edureka in youtube. Tried uninstall and reinstalling method. I transferred files from a laptop where the code work and yet, still no good.

```
package testing;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice.Enter;

public class test_1 {

    WebDriver driver;

    public void invokeBrowser() {

    try {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Files\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://google.com/");
        LogIn();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test_1 myObj = new test_1();
    myObj.invokeBrowser();

    }
}
```

then here's the error

```
Exception in thread "main"
org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException: 
FOUND:
INTERNAL ERROR: Oops!
Exiting!!
    at     
org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException.main(AssertionViolatedException.java:102)
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609066/getting-following-exception-org-apache-bcel-verifier-exc-assertionviolatedexcept

Comment: There's already a thread with the same question but there was no steps or procedure on how to fix the error we're encountering.